# Cardinality of the set of all functions from A to B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, let $F(A, B)$ denote the set of all functions $f : A → B $ (no assumptions about injectivity or surjectivity – all functions from $A$ to $B$ are included). Let $|S|$ denote the cardinality of a set S.

a) If A and B are finite, with |A| = n and |B| = m, show that F(A,B) is finite and determine |F (A, B)|.

**b) Let S be any finite set of cardinality greater than 1. Show that $F(N,S)$ is uncountable, but $F(S,N)$ is countable.**

---

Comment: Your answer is correct. $|F(A,B)|=|B|^{|A|}$

Comment: You got it right.  $|F(A,B)| = |B|^{|A|} = m^n$. Exactly as you reasoned.  Because of this result, if $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $F= \{f | f:A\mapsto B\}$ must be finite.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for checking the answer, any ideas to show it's finite?

Comment: Your reasoning shows it is finite.  B provides only a finite number of choices for each of the elements in A, which are finite.

Comment: It's generally quite rude to **completely** change a part of your question that was already answered. And if you did make such an edit, the least you can do is leave comments to the people who answered and let them know of the change.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am so sorry for that. I am somewhat new to this site. I will keep this in mind from now on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** The product of finitely many countable sets is countable; and $F(\Bbb N,\{0,1\})$ is uncountable due to Cantor's theorem, finally show that if $|S|\leq|T|$ and $A$ is any set then $|F(A,S)|\leq|F(A,T)|$.